# Liferay - Resize and convert image type DLFileEntry in Documents and Media

Tags: java, image, liferay

I wanted to edit the images from Document and Media by converting their formats (say JPG to PNG) and by re-sizing their heights and width.

I tried to implement the following code for converting.

```
DLFileEntry dlFileEntry = DLFileEntryServiceUtil.getFileEntry(dlFileEntryId);
dlFileEntry.setExtension("png");
dlFileEntry.setMimeType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE);
dlFileEntry.setTitle("Nature.png");
dlFileEntry = DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.updateDLFileEntry(dlFileEntry);
```

Even though it updated the database with the corresponding PNG values, it did not change the content type of the image in Documents and Media.

[image]

Also, I could not come up with a method to resize the fileEntry yet.
Is there a way to convert and resize these images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry but...

how can you think that a single line `dlFileEntry.setExtension("png");` is enough to convert the image file format?

Use `ImageToolUtil` to resize and convert file format, and then reload the file using DLAppServiceUtil.